# Passing flask.request to another thread

Tags: python, flask, thread-safety

I'm a bit confused about whether I can or cannot send Flask's `request` object to another thread for processing. I'm trying to store request related data in Elasticsearch using `after_request`. To handle the request as fast as possible, I'm trying to offload the processing to a separate thread:

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket
from threading import Thread

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from flask import current_app, request

def after_request(response):
    Thread(
        target=_process_data, args=(
            current_app._get_current_object(),
            request._get_current_object()
        )
    ).start()

    return response

def _process_data(app, request):
    data = {
        'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
        'scheme': request.environ.get('REQUEST_SCHEME'),
        'protocol': request.environ.get('SERVER_PROTOCOL'),
        'method': request.environ.get('REQUEST_METHOD'),
        'uri': request.environ.get('REQUEST_URI'),
        'remote_addr': request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR'),
        'remote_port': int(request.environ.get('REMOTE_PORT')),
        'server_name': request.environ.get('SERVER_NAME'),
        'server_port': int(request.environ.get('SERVER_PORT')),
        'app_server': socket.gethostname(),
        'request_headers': dict(request.headers)
    }

    elastic = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
    elastic.index(index=app.config['TRACKING_ES_INDEX'], doc_type='_doc', body=data)
```

However, what I started seeing in Elasticsearch are documents with empty `request_headers` field (`{}`), especially when load-testing the app. When I tried to move filling the `data` dictionary to `after_request` and passing `data` to `_process_data` instead, everything works as expected.

The [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context) states:

> The context is unique to each thread (or other worker type). request cannot be passed to another thread, the other thread will have a different context stack and will not know about the request the parent thread was pointing to.

However, [couple of paragraphs later](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies), it states:

> The reference to the proxied object is needed in some situations, such as sending Signals or passing data to a background thread.

So I assumed that using `request._get_current_object()` to get the actual object and passing it to the separated thread would work. But apparently, there is something that I'm missing...

Comment: Do you have an exception? Also you don't need to do this with flask. If you run your server with Gunicorn or similar it handles this sort of thing for you. You might want to pass off work like this to Celery or similary to reduce _response_ time but this won't affect the number of requests you can handle simultaneously. This solution just adds complexity I think.

Comment: I do not have any exception, I would indeed provide that _detail_ if I had. Also, how would WSGI server handle this for me? And finally, I'm aware I can use a task queue but that's not what I'm after now.

Comment: The intricacy is whether you are trying to return to the user as quickly as possible or whether you are trying to handle as many requests as possible. Gunicron uses Gevent which basically async-ifies synchronous python code to enable the latter. If you want to return as quickly as possible, you want a task queue. Using the above pattern can get nasty quick; what happens if that thread fails? It's also expensive to spin up OS threads. What happens if those threads don't terminate properly? etc

Comment: I'm aware of all the possible caveats, but this question is not about those architectural decisions. I'm specifically seeking an answer to the question of thread-safety of `flask.request` which I wasn't able to find in the documentation nor searching the Internet.

Comment: Try it, you literally have the code. Then you can determine if it's thread safe or not. If I were you I'd be looking to serialise the request with pickle, shelve or json and pass this to a background thread where you can do whatever you like outisde of the application context.